# How to pass variables from php page to aspx page and retrieve return value from aspx to php

Tags: c#, php, asp.net

Can you please tell how to pass variables from php to aspx page, and how aspx can retrieve that values? after retrieving these values , aspx should return a 'success' response to php . php page should echo it . 
found that can redirect to aspx using

```
$url = "http://www.xxx.co/Default.aspx" ;
$param = "?" . "Field1=" . $num . "&Field2=" . $name . ";
header('Location: ' . $url . $param);
```

Comment: What is the actual problem here?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<?php
$retString= file_get_contents($url . $param);
echo $retString;
?>
```

to get value back from other web page.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with `CURL`as to show an alternative for using `file_get_contents`. As you are not explaining if you are using post or get I have build an example with get, but if you are going to use post, then ´CURL` is the best solution.

```
$url = "http://www.xxx.co/Default.aspx" ;
$param = "?" . "Field1=" . $num . "&Field2=" . $name;

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url. $param,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    return "error: " . $err;
} else {
    return $response;
}
```